# How to correctly add HKRoute to HKWorkout

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

How should I correctly add route to workout in HealthKit. I am always getting results where route is not continuous, see [route in HK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ZSy.jpg)

First I create array of CLLocations

```
// DISTANCE - ROUTE
        for location in workout.samples {
            if location.latitude.value == nil {
                continue
            }
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude.value ?? 0.0, location.longitude.value ?? 0.0)
            let altitude = location.altitude.value ?? 0.0
            let speed = location.speed.value ?? 0.0
            let course = location.course.value ?? 0.0
            let timestamp = location.timestamp
            let accuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            let coreLocation = CLLocation(coordinate: coordinates, altitude: altitude, horizontalAccuracy: accuracy, verticalAccuracy: accuracy, course: course, speed: speed, timestamp: timestamp)

            locations.append(coreLocation)
        }
```

And then once insert the array to RouteBuilder and FinishRoute, see

```
if workout.existDistance() {
        routeBuilder.insertRouteData(locations) { (state, error) in
            print (error ?? "no error inserting data to route")
            routeBuilder.finishRoute(with: workoutHK, metadata: nil) { (completion, error) in
                print(error ?? "no error finishing route")
            }
        }
    }

    healthStore.save(workoutHK) { (finished, error) in
        if finished {
            self.healthStore.add(samples, to: workoutHK) { (completion, error) in
                print (error ?? "no error adding samples")
            }

            completion(true)
            print(error ?? "no error saving workout")
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
```

When I export my Location samples to GPX and use a different app for saving the workout to the HealthKit it works just fine, so data itself should be ok, I tried already different CLLocation inits but nothing seems to help.

Comment: I am seeing the exact same problem. Also that some of my workouts are displayed in the Fitness app with a map and others without. But all are saved the same way.
Would be super glad if you could tell me more about your findings! Did you solve the problem?